# Template "Unmatched Relationship Tag"

Tags: ee2, templates, relationships

I'm trying to get a multi-entry relationship field to render in a template using EE 2.6.0, however I'm getting "Unmatched Relationship Tag: "{impact_stats}"" with template debugging enabled, with it disabled I get nothing with the conditional, without the conditional it just outputs the actual tags and not their contents.

This is the code I'm using, it's contained within a exp:channel:entries loop and all of the entry's tags other than the impact_stats one is working.

```
{if impact_stats}
<section class="content-stats-listing">
    <div class="row">
        {impact_stats}
        <article class="module-stats note av-fire">
            <h4>{impact_stats:headline}</h4>
            <p>{impact_stats:description}</p>
        </article>
        {/impact_stats}
    </div>
</section>
{/if}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the template parser is *thinking* that your conditional is the opening variable of a pair.

Try this:

```
{impact_stats}
    {if impact_stats:count == 1}
    <section class="content-stats-listing">
        <div class="row">
    {/if}
            <article class="module-stats note av-fire">
                <h4>{impact_stats:headline}</h4>
                <p>{impact_stats:description}</p>
            </article>
    {if impact_stats:count == impact_stats:total_results}
        </div>
    </section>
    {/if}
{/impact_stats}
```

Comment: It looks like my main issue was the {color} html comment, another dev added it and that tag doesn't exist so it must have been causing the parsing issue. However once I removed it still wasn't working with my original code, your code solved the issue. Thanks!